# psycopg2 - how to change NULL type to a string 'NA' instead of None

Tags: python, psycopg2

psycopg2 converts NULL to None through the NoneAdapter (right?)
How do I create another adapter that converts all NULL to a string 'NA' ?

Thanks

*UPDATE:
@thatisbrilliant
Here is what i have:
After doing this query :

```
SELECT pg_type.oid
FROM pg_type JOIN pg_namespace
    ON typnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
WHERE typname = 'point'
    AND nspname = 'pg_catalog';
```

and get the `point_oid` = 600 so I continue with this:

```
def NA(value, cur):
    if value is None:
        return 'NA'
    return value
None2NA = psycopg2.extensions.new_type((600,), 'None2NA', NA)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(None2NA)
```

Doesn't work o.o  it still returns None

Comment: Is there any reason why `COALESCE()` won't work?

Comment: because I won't know which columns will be null, and there are just many many columns I can't do it for all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually NoneAdapter does the opposite of what you want, converts python's None type into SQL NULL. For info on casting SQL types into python objects, check out the [official psycopg2 documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html#type-casting-of-sql-types-into-python-objects).

Based on that, it looks like you will have to register your adapter function for every type you want it to work on, but I assume the function would simply be:

```
def NA(value, cur):
    if value is None:
        return 'NA'
    return value
```

Then register with `psycopg2.extensions.new_type` and `psycopg2.extensions.register_type`.

Comment: so I have to register new type for each cursor result I get?e.g: `result = curs.fetchone()[0]; psycopg2.extensions.new_type((result,), 'NA', NA) ; psycopg2.extensions.register_type('NA');` ? what if i have this `results = curs.fetchall()` that means I have to loop through the `results` and register new type for each of them?

Comment: @BPm No, you only have to register once at the beginning of your program. The first parameter of `new_type` is a tuple containing the OIDs for every type (char, numeric, etc) you want the adapter applied to. And lose the semi-colons.

Comment: @BPm The example in the documentation applies an adapter to the `point` type. If you want yours to work for other types, get the OID for each type by replacing `point` in that query with the type name. Then you can register the adapter for multiple types at once. For example, `None2NA = psycopg2.extensions.new_type((1700,1043), 'None2NA', NA)` will apply it to `numeric` and `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
row = cux.fetchone()
field = row[col] if row[col] is not None else 'NA'
```

Done!

If you want to apply it to all the columns in the row, use map():

row = map(lambda x: x if x is not None else 'NA', cux.fetchone())

Comment: this will not work for values that evaluate to False in Python like 0 or a blank string; use `field = row[col] if row[col] is not None else 'NA'` if you want to make distinction between NULL and values that evaluate to False.

Comment: I could do a loop, check for None value and append 'NA' to it. But that's not what I want, because it's a pretty big list

Comment: @PauloScardine Good catch. I've updated my answer with your suggestion.